# Are there any utilities available on Ubuntu that convert bootable USBs to ISOs?

Tags: usb, iso

I have a bootable USB for installing Windows 10, and I wish to install Windows 10 on a Virtualbox machine. Is there any way to convert the files in the USB into an ISO?

Answer (score 1):

This command will make complete copy of your device, replace the name with name `sdx` of your device:

`dd bs=4M if=/dev/sdx of=/windows10.iso status=progress && sync`

Alternative: mount your usb to VirtualBox and install from it.

Comment: Win 10 iso is about 4 GB. If pendrive is 8 GB or more you will have such large iso file.

Comment: 1. This will work independently of distro jr utils installed. 2. thats why I add the install-from-usb suggestion ;)